# RESTful API with relationships

Tags: rest, api, join, relationship, many-to-one

Lets assume I'm building an API for a restaurant and I have the following resources:

`Donut(has_chocolate,has_sprinkles)`

and

`Receipt(cost,donut_id)`

My Web App will want to display a table of `receipts` for the manager to view. Unfortunately the `receipt` object by itself isn't useful enough, the manager needs to see whether the `donut` has chocolate or not.

How best do I do this - I can think of 3 implementations:

1) Do a JOIN and return the `receipt` resource with the `has_chocolate` additional field

2) Do a JOIN and return the `receipt` resource with a `donut` object containing ALL relevant `donut` information

3) Pull in a page of `receipt` objects, collect and de-duplicate the `donut_ids`, and use them to pull in the required `donut` objects - either one at a time `/donut/id`, or all at once `/donuts?ids=id1,id2,id3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RESTful API should have endpoints that resolve to a resource or a collection of resources. You can then do an HTTP verb on that endpoint, in this case a GET. Therefore you need to make a decision about how do you define your resources for the API user?

Are there two resources, donuts and receipts, like in your SQL?
Do you want to define a donut as a resource that has a receipt as one of the fields?

Either is fine, the problem is when you start making routes that are a resource 'with something extra on top'. That starts to become hard for the consumer to understand and not RESTful.

If it were me I would choose option 3.

- Define two separate endpoints for collections of donuts and receipts: `/v0/donuts/` and `/v0/receipts/`
- Allow the consumer to join on the client side by exposing the neccessary filters `/v0/donuts/?ids=1,2,3,8`

You could make a `/v0/events/< id>/` route but seeing as the use-case is to always get a batch of donuts then this would result in too many round-trips for the consumer.

It also sounds like you want to paginate these collections. In this case you should define a `max_page_size`, `default_page_size` and you should return your client a `next_page` field in the response (which is null if it's the last page). You would also have to decide what to paginate on, probably the id in this case.